# How can I find a lens locking screw if I have lost the original one?

Tags: lens, focus, optics, astrophotography, laser

I have an industrial camera with a C-mount lens, like this one:

[image]

([Source of image](https://www.baslerweb.com/fp-1481127650/media/editorial/product_images/accessories/lenses/Lens_Edmund_Optics_CFFL_F18_f12mm_2_3_2000035066_670x500px__x250.jpg), last accessed 2022.11.02.)

You can see a tiny screw on the top of the picture. It is used to lock the focus ring or other rings, depending on the actual lens. How can I buy one, if I have lost the one that came originally with the lens?

I suppose it is some kind of "10 pcs for 1 dollar" thing from [eBay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) or [AliExpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AliExpress)? But how can I find it? I tried searching for a long time, but no meaningful results showed up.

(Also a longer one would be more useful than those tiny ones that came with the lens.)

Comment: Edmund optics have been helpful for me in the past.  They may tell you (or they may just try to sell you a very expensive replacement).  Do you have vernier calipers to measure the inner diameter and look it up.  That could narrow it down to a couple of sizes (I wouldn't assume metric - US-based optics firms and their suppliers still use a lot of imperial fixings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to check it with a micrometer gauge and a thread comb.

The thread is metric, with nominal diameter 1.6 mm, and pitch 0.35.

After proper googling as @hobbs pointed out, I finally identified the screws.
This google search gives the exact results:
"M1,6 knurled screw"

:)

Answer (score 6):

You first need to know what the thread size is, which you could find from the manufacturer, or by using a thread gauge. I would be inclined to e-mail the manufacturer, asking for a replacement Iris Locking Screw for your lens. If you go to their website, they have a live engineer chat feature that you could make use of too.

Alternatively, buy a selection box of metric and imperial screws from a hardware store or reputable online retailer, and find one that fits.

Comment: The last C mount lens I swapped out the locking screw on (replacing it with a grub screw to save space), the thread was M2. I doubt you will find M2 screws in a selection box from a hardware store and good luck using any type of thread gauge on a female thread that small.

Comment: Assuming you do identify the thread, search for a "M# x #mm thumb screw" or "knurled screw", where it's okay (but mildly annoying) if the length is a little too long, but if it's too short then it won't lock anything.

Comment: @PeterGreen Searching on Amazon for "small metric screws" brings up assortment boxes with screws of sizes M1, M2, and many in-betweens.

Comment: @JoL On amazon, yes. At a brick & mortar hardware store, very unlikely.

Comment: @MichaelC really? Not sure were you're located, but Midwest USA I'd be able to find this in <5 minutes at Lowe's.

Comment: The have M1.6 knurled screws at your Lowe's? Congratulations. I don't think Lowe's in my area does.